# PHP Codeigniter Multiple Level Switch Statements

Tags: php, switch-statement, codeigniter-2

I am re-building a website with PHP codeigniter that contains mostly static pages and some dynamic pages interspersed. The problem is, the pages are 1-5 layers deep within the navigation (ex. example.com/about/history/people/person/photos).

I'm not sure how to implement this in the controller. I currently have a crazy set of switch statements nested in switch statements. Here is a simple example:

```
class About extends MY_Controller 
{
//**** INDEX page ****                    
public function index()
    {
        $this->setTitle('About');
        $this->setDescription('About Stuff');
        $this->loadView('about/index');
    }

 //-------------------------HISTORY section--------------------------------
public function history($sub1 = "", $sub2 = "", $sub3 = "", $sub4 = "")
{
    $path = "";

    switch($sub1){

        //_____ PEOPLE section ____
        case 'people':
            switch($sub2){

                //____ PERSON section ____
                case 'person':
                        switch($sub3){ 

                            //**** PHOTOS page ****
                            case 'photos':
                                $this->setTitle('Photos');
                                $this->setDescription('Photo stuff');
                                $path = 'people/person/photos';
                                break;

                            //**** DOCUMENTS page ****
                            case 'documents':
                                //Load special scripts
                                $this->setTitle('Documents');
                                $this->setDescription('Document stuff');
                                $path = 'people/person/documents';
                                break;

                             //**** INDEX page ****
                             default:
                                $this->setTitle('Person');
                                $this->setDescription('Person stuff');
                                $path = 'people/person/index';
                        }
                        break;

                //**** AnotherPerson page *****
                case 'anotherPerson':
                     //Load database
                     $this->setTitle('AnotherPerson');
                     $this->setDescription('AnotherPerson stuff');
                     $path = 'people/anotherperson';
                     break;

                //**** INDEX page ****
                default:
                    $this->setTitle('People');
                    $this->setDescription('People stuff');
                    $path = 'people/index';

            }
            break;


        //**** INDEX page ****
        default:
            $this->setTitle('History');
            $this->setDescription('History stuff');
            $path = 'index';
    }


            $this->loadView('about/history/' . $path );

}
}
```

I feel like I am approaching this incorrectly and it feels messy. So my question is: Is there a better (more compact/clean/dynamic) way of doing this?

Comment: You can create a custom router that will allow you to add controllers in subfolders (see http://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/) for an example - in that case, it only allows a single subfolder, but it can be extended to traverse deeper

Comment: Thank you! This is something that I could definitely make work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.

1. You could put the case statements in separate function. eg. if you've `case 'documents'` you could put this into a private function:

   private function documents(){
          //Load special scripts
          $this->setTitle('Documents');
          $this->setDescription('Document stuff');
          $path = 'people/person/documents';
   }
2. You could make an associative array with the title, description etc. in it and check if the variables are filled. After this you can call the array by with the `$sub` vars.